# Why were eastern European states larger than western European states for much of history?

Tags: europe, government, early-modern

For reference, ever since the Treaty of Verdun in 843, large, centralized states in western Europe seemed to be the exception rather than the norm. Of course, there are exceptions, such as England and France, however, I would note that the centralization of the French state would occur later, especially moving into the period of absolute monarchs and centralization as a result of the reformation in the 16th and 17th centuries. The Spanish kingdom doesn't appear until 1516 with the ascension of Charles I. This seems to be in contrast with more eastern states. Examples would include Bohemia, Hungary, Poland, Lithuania, the Ottoman Empire, and even Russian precursor states such as the Grand Duchy of Moscow and Novgorod Republic all taking up large portions of land. My impression is that they were relatively more centralized than their western counterparts.

Two answers that come to mind are that eastern Europe was less dense than western Europe, and therefore the larger states ruled over a similar number of people as the smaller western states. The second reason is that my impression of centralization could be mistaken for the eastern states, in that they might be less centralized than I thought.

As a final thought, the end of this imbalance seems to be after the Napoleonic wars and perhaps even until the 1870's with the unification of Germany and Italy doing away with many of the small, disparate states that lead to my original thought. Does this mean that the end of this dynamic was brought about by nationalism? Perhaps it could also be the emergence of more modern governments brought about by the Napoleonic Wars that enabled larger western states.

Comment: The concept of a "state" doesn't really apply during most of the time period you're talking about.

Comment: I realize that statehood as a concept is usually something reserved for after the 30 year's war; I found it useful term to generalize the concept of a region ruled by a sovereign (instead of mentioning kingdoms, commonwealths, duchies, etc.)

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Relies on assertions without evidence. Seems to advance a theory to test.

Comment: The Ottoman Empire was an Asian Empire that conquered large parts of Eastern Europe, much like the Golden Horde to the north. Similarly much of Spain and Portugal were part of various Islamic caliphates. Nationalism had nothing to do with it, nationalism was the result of crumbling empires in the early 20th century where nations of people formed countries based on language and traditions. Napoleon reorganised the German States into fewer larger ones. You should consider the geography too and direction of rivers. Several horse cultures have pushed into eastern Europe this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your generalizations about both Western and Eastern Europe are completely unfounded. For example:

- The Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth was no more centralized than the Holy Roman Empire, and perhaps even less so: the H.R.E. morphed into a Prussian led German State shortly after Poland disappeared completely.
- Large swaths of France were under English (and Burgundian) suzerainty for much of the 4 centuries from 1066 to 1453.
- Spain underwent a 7 1/2 century long civil war known as *Reconquista* from the Battle of Tours (732) until the fall of Granada (1492).
- First Muslim and then Norman invaders controlled most of Southern Italy for centuries.
- The Baltic states were a hodgepodge of semi-sovereign duchies when they weren't (nominally) subordinate.
- The Ottomans controlled most of the Balkans, most of the time, from shortly after the Fourth Crusade until well into the 19th century.
- England twice, during The Anarchy and again during Wars of the Roses, was a completely decentralized state.

That's just a partial list of exceptions, that far outnumbers your examples.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood my question. Half of my entire point was that western Europe remained decentralized for so long as compared to the east. Your points 2,3,4,6, and 7 speak to that decentralization. As for the first point, I noted that this trend was mostly over after the Napoleonic Wars, which as you so noted marked the end of the HRE and its replacement by the German Confederation (that I would argue is more a Prussian-Austrian led alliance system than a "Prussian led German State.")

Comment: @Corsair64: There are more natural borders in Western Europe than in the East; However there is absolutely nothing unified about the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth. (1) it's a personal union not a single sovereignty. (2) Much of it was de facto independent (East Prussia, Courland, Kiev) just as in H.R.E. (3) Western Europe didn't have to deal with Mongol invaders, and then throw off their yoke. The semblance of centralization you see is a charade, just like the Wizard of Oz behind the curtain.